# how to make folders in my android app

Tags: android

i have spent a lot of time now on searching on how to make folders in my app, what i usually found was how to make folders for my activities or for layout files but what i couldn't make google understand was i need folders just like we open the gallery in our phones and it has many folders like screenshots, whatsapp images, facebook images, camera images etc.. My query is somewhat similar.. I know in technical language it is called something else but i now wonder whether it is possible in android. If it is please enlighten me about it.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The gallery consists presumably of a GridView, GridLayout or TableLayout. There are no "folders" in Android.